# Why my app doesn't support nexus 7?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-market-filtering

I uploaded my app to the market and they said that it isn't compatible with nexus 7 though it works fine in it. I read many questions regard this case such as,
[My App not supporting nexus 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825696/my-app-not-supporting-nexus-7) or [App not available for Nexus 7 on Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290295/app-not-available-for-nexus-7-on-google-play). However, I don't think it is related to my problem because I don't use the camera permission in my app.

Here is my Manifest file (permissions & support-screens):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    .....>
```

I am not sure if this is a duplicate issue but I really can't figure it out. Any tip will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of Nexus 7 has Android 4.3 (API 18) - that's the reason.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice it thanks. I hope it works

Comment: Let me know if it does, so I can put this as an answer. :)

Comment: There are dozens of apps that specify target sdk as lower values and they work on higher sdks. Or it may be something related to screen sizes or strictly to nexus7?

Comment: are you usung any <uses-feature> tag?

Comment: @gunary Well that what I thought but it seems that the application on works for the targeted SDKs.

Comment: @Arun no I didn't use any <uses-feature> tags.

Comment: @OsamaEspil What did you do to get it working?

Comment: Just changed the android:targetSDKVersion = "18"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments section:

> Of Nexus 7 has Android 4.3 (API 18) - that's the reason.

By default it's with Android 4.1, but since it's a Nexus device, it might have 4.3 installed (which is API 18).

Comment: that can't be the reason

Answer (score -2):

change your manifest to this..

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

becaue nexus 7 uses android api 18 that is latest **JellyBean....**

Comment: `android:targetSdkVersion` has no effect on Play Store filtering.

Comment: play store requires minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion can't be the case